# safari is overrriding input text default value in cakephp3

Tags: forms, safari, credentials, cakephp-3.2

When using safari browser for a cakephp3.2 application it overrides the default value set in the txtbox. In another browser eg Firefox in windows or IE I get the correct output being displayed as default value.

I have tried this in firefox 66 win10 running cakephp3.2 php7 and mysql 5.7
Also tried this on safari browser 11.0.2 on a mac OS

echo $this->Form->input('username',array("label"=>false, "class"=>"form-control",  'value'=>$tutor->user->username));?>

the results differ on each browser. The correct output is in firefox browser on windows
eg myemail@gmail.com

safari on MacOs overrides the value and instead places in another email used to login to the application
eg login@gmail.com

Comment: That has nothing to do with CakePHP, but everything with how Safari (and browsers in general) uses stored credentials. **https://www.google.com/search?q=safari+autofill+overrides+form+value+site:stackoverflow.com** | **https://www.google.com/search?q=safari+ignores+autocomplete+off+site:stackoverflow.com**

Comment: by removing the website from the edit forms option has not solved the issue. It keeps auto filling the form with a username  https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/safari/autofill-ibrwa005/mac